# Regex for string that starts but doesn't end with "

Tags: regex

Is there an option to write a regex that represents strings that start with `"` and **don't end with** `"` ?

Comment: what flavour of RegEx? http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the regex:

```
^".*[^"]$
```

Explanation:

```
^     Start of line anchor
"     A literal "
.*    Any junk
[^"]  Any non " character
$     End of line anchor
```

Comment: lol Stackoverflow gives almost instant answers. It's like google for harder problems :)

Comment: You should submit this to Stack's management as their new byline :-)

Answer (score 3):

There you go:

```
^".*[^"]$

^" starts with "
.* some chars (or none)
[^"]$ doesn't end with "
```

Comment: Not quite right - a single quote then another nonquote should match given OP's reqs, but your regex would not. your regex needs at least 3 chars to match

Comment: I assumed "strings" would mean more than one character. But okay then, I'll amend...

Answer (score 2):

Here you go

```
^".*[^"]$
```

What regex engine are you using?